# Parsing "request" field from AWS ELB logs

Tags: ruby, parsing, amazon-web-services, logstash, grok

I've enabled the access logs for my ELB's on AWS, and we're sending them to a setup of logstash + elasticsearch + kibana.
I'm using logstash's grok filter to parse the logs into separate fields that i can view and sort in kibana, and running into a difficulty with parsing the last field that amazon give in those logs, which is the "request" field.
it contains actually 3 parts. the HTTP method, the URL itself and the HTTP version.

how can i separate those 3 into independent fields that i could use?

Thanks
Benyamin

Comment: Please show what you've tried, the results, and what you have figured out as far as why it doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: this is the grok filter I currently use: `match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{NOTSPACE:loadbalancer} %{IP:client_ip}:%{NUMBER:client_port:int} %{IP:backend_ip}:%{NUMBER:backend_port:int} %{NUMBER:request_processing_time:float} %{NUMBER:backend_processing_time:float} %{NUMBER:response_processing_time:float} %{NUMBER:elb_status_code:int} %{NUMBER:backend_status_code:int} %{NUMBER:received_bytes:int} %{NUMBER:sent_bytes:int} %{QS:request}" ]`.

Comment: that last field, "request" gives back a string like this: `"\"GET https://example.com:443/template/genGetPCServerA11.xml?im‌​eiPar=9dfbaa0af01edea&versionPar=3000000&userPar=%2B919910030185&appType=6 HTTP/1.1\""`. and I'm not sure how to separate this string into the 3 mentioned parts. I was thinking to try awk and grep but I dont know how to incorporate them into the logstash config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this, to replace the last element of your grok filter?

```
\"%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request} HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}\"
```

I've never actually administered logstash before, but I pieced this together by looking at the source code for the built-in filters, some of which are evidently built on top of other built-in filters.

https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash/blob/v1.4.1/patterns/grok-patterns

This pattern should extract three elements, the "verb" would capture "GET" and the "httpversion" would capture the numeric HTTP version, and the "request" would capture the rest.

I admit I'm also guessing about the backslashes to escape the double quote literals that are in the message, but that seems like the logical way to include a literal quote to match the ones that ELB puts in the logs.  Note that the final double-quote I've shown isn't the closing quote of the filter string expression. That quote would go immediately after the above, since this matches the last thing on each line.

Comment: if I may ask another thing on the same thread - any idea how I can parse the rest of the parameters in the url? for example the file that is being requested (in this case `genGetPCServerA11.xml`, and then the other params that follow (im‌​eiPar, versionPar, userPar, appType) ?

Comment: Take a look at the source code at the link I posted.  Note how the `URI` filter references the `URIPATHPARAM` filter and go from there.  Once you have a handle on regular expressions, particularly the concept of optional matches, you should be able to extract anything you need.